# mysql query for ohlc performance

Tags: mysql, performance

OK maybe someone already asked the question but I really couldn't find any help yet.
I have MySQL table of trade with some historical data that looks like this:

```
+----+------------+---------+--------+-----------+------------+-----+----------------+
| id | date       | price   | amount | price_int | amount_int | tid | price_currency |
+----+------------+---------+--------+-----------+------------+-----+----------------+
| 1  | 1279408157 | 0.04951 | 20     | 4951      | 2000000000 | 1   | USD            |
+----+------------+---------+--------+-----------+------------+-----+----------------+

+------+------------+---------+------------+
| item | trade_type | primary | properties |
+------+------------+---------+------------+
| XXX  | market     | Y       | limit      |
+------+------------+---------+------------+
```

I'm trying to query the table to get something like this:

```
+-------------+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+--------+-----------+
| day         | count | O       | H       | L       | C       | V      | AV        |
+-------------+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+--------+-----------+
| 2013-11-25  | 30    | 0.04951 | 0.05321 | 0.04935 | 0.04963 | 8.5246 | 255.73800 |
+-------------+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+--------+-----------+
```

Now I cam up with this query:

```
SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`)) AS `day`,
    COUNT(*) AS `tot`,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(`price_int` AS CHAR) ORDER BY `date`), ',', 1 ) as `O`,
    MAX(`price_int`) AS `H`,
    MIN(`price_int`) AS `L`,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(`price_int` AS CHAR) ORDER BY `date` DESC), ',', 1 ) as `C`,
    SUM(`amount`) AS `V`
    AVG(`amount`) AS `AV`
FROM   `trades`
WHERE `primary`='Y'
GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`))
ORDER BY `day`  ASC
```

Now, my problem is in performance: I get 13.9531 sec to query 2,559,116 rows. Also i'm not yet dome to gather all the data and I estimate to be the final table to be around 5-6 Million.

### is there a better way to write the query? or maybe some kind of caching or workaround to get better timing?